# Matlab Image Surface plot across color channels

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I am new to image processing and want to plot the color channels using surf to study the intensities in different color channels and their peaks or if they get cut off or saturated at any point. Can someone direct me as to where I can learn how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) command directly to do just this. When you pass a 2D array to `surf`, it uses the values as the height (z) and uses `1:size(data, 2)` for the x values and `1:size(data, 1)` for the y values.

```
figure
hax = axes;
hold(hax, 'on');

rsurf = surf(img(:,:,1), 'FaceColor', 'r', 'FaceAlpha', 0.5, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
bsurf = surf(img(:,:,2), 'FaceColor', 'b', 'FaceAlpha', 0.5, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
gsurf = surf(img(:,:,3), 'FaceColor', 'g', 'FaceAlpha', 0.5, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
```

As an example

```
img = reshape(parula(16), [4 4 3]);
```

[image]

Comment: Ill play around with these a little bit. Its works for now. I want to see what Information I can extract from it. Thanks though